# Vauxhall Corsa 1.3 CDTI Thermostat replacement?

Tags: vauxhall, thermostat, corsa

My Vauxhall Corsa 1.3 CDTi 2011's thermostat is stuck open so I am going to have to buy a new thermostat, the problem is I have no experience with car maintenance or repair, I haven't been able to find anything on-line so far either as it's not a very common model of the car.

I would like to know where abouts the thermostat is located also if anyone has experience doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which year model is it?

Comment: @Zaid Sorry yes it is the 2011 Limited edition

Comment: The thermostat is usually located where the upper radiator hose meets the block. I think you'll need to take the top cover off to find it (I was just looking at some pictures of your application.)

Comment: Please add a picture if you have one that would show the exact location of the housing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest investing in a Haynes Manual for this car.  One minor repair like this that you can do yourself will pay for it in savings.

This is the part you are looking for, it's the thermostat housing, that I found on eBay.  If I recall, it was for the 2011.
[image]

Here is a video on how to [change it a thermostat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p25MiNwz-_s) for a Vauxhall Corsa 1.3 (2004).  Now it may be in a slightly different location, but usually changing a thermostat won't change that much over the years.

If I can find one for your exact year, I will include it, but this is the best I could find for now.  I couldn't find the exact location in a picture anywhere.  Due to the lack of information, it may be a bit of work to actually to get to the housing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thermostart can be situated any where in the water line of the engine either at the top or at the base of the block where the hose meet

Comment: Are you being specific to this vehicle/engine? Or are you just throwing it out there? We welcome answers, no doubt, but you'll find out answers like these will get downvoted because they are too generic and really don't do anything to answer the question. Please read selections in [the Help Center](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) for better ways to write answers.

Comment: I am a toyota technician so I can say a lot about automobiles generally bcos in some engines in toyota some are located at the lower block where coolant goes in to the engine while some at the upper part it depends on the engine model and manufacturers design more so I haven't come across such a vehicle but from experience the location of thermostart can be found on either one of the sides. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. While I understand your point, you are just being general. In this case, it really doesn't help the OP solve the issue. The OP is very specific about the year/make/model/engine of their vehicle. With that in mind, you should be able to say where the t-stat is at with confidence. It's only a suggestion to you as we are looking for specific, not vague answers. Like I said, we appreciate your willingness to share your knowledge. I'm just trying to help you write a better answer.